# How to copy 2 columns from many Excel files into a new Excel file with Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, os.path

I need to copy 2 columns (H and E) from several Excel files and paste them into a new Excel file. In the new Excel file, I would like to put the pasted columns one after the other since I have to make a graph to compare data coming from the different Excel files.
I tried this code but it just copies several times the columns of just one Excel file. Could you please help me? Thanks

```
    import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import ScatterChart, Reference, Series
import os, os.path
import fnmatch



# I create the new Excel file
wb=openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet=wb.active
wb.save('Comparison.xlsx')
folder=r'C:\\Users\\PycharmProjects\\output\\'

#here I count the number of Excel files in the folder
numb=(len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(folder), '*.xlsx')))


def compare_graph(file):
    #I open the Excel files from which I want to copy columns H and E
    wb1=openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(folder, file))
    sheet1=wb1['Sheet']
    #I copy the columns into the new Excel file
    for i in range(1,sheet1.max_row+1):
        for j in range(1, numb+1):
            cell1 = sheet1.cell(row=i, column=8)
            cell2 = sheet1.cell(row=i, column=5)
            if sheet.cell(i,2j).value is None:
                sheet.cell(row=i,column=2j).value=cell1.value
                sheet.cell(row=i, column=2j+1).value = cell2.value
            
    wb.save('Comparison.xlsx')


file_to_take=os.listdir(folder)
for file_in in file_to_take:
    compare_graph(file_in)
```

Comment: In the `compare_graph` function you dont instantiate the file parameter..

Comment: @TorbenIT `file` is passed in as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Yes, I noticed and bypassed it with passing a filename as a string to the function

Comment: Do you mean `sheet1=wb1['Sheet1']` ?

Comment: It's worth noting that `file` is a reserved word in Python so best not to get into the habit of overwriting it. The code for copying cell values could be clearer and easier.

Comment: I am aware, I've being using Python since 2 weeks so I am not an expert at all. I have replaced 'file' with 'filename', do you have any other suggestions to fix and improve my code? Thanks a lot